Detecting Un-Known license package "Vulcan.Maui.Template" while scanning MAUI project in Black Duck
We have created project in MAUI, and using Black duck for security vulnerabilities while scanning the MAUI application with Black duck it got detected "Vulcan.Maui.Template" package for Android and MacCatalyst projects but we haven't installed any such packages and there is no references for the same. Could you please help in this.
Please refer the below image for the reference.

And below is the content of the Android and MacCatalyst projects

Steps to Reproduce

Create a MAUI application.
Scan the application using Black Duck.
The Black duck tool detecting un-known license package
"Vulcan.Maui.Template" In Android and MacCatalyst projects.

